# .NET build output verification

Tags: .net, build, verification

I have a .NET solution which consist of around 100 projects. At the end of the build I'd like to verify that all files needed for the application to run are created in the output directory (e.g. assemblies, config files, help files, data files, ...).

Are there any tools available or how do you do this in your projects?

Comment: "I have a .NET project which consist of around 100 projects" Do you meean a .NET *solution*?

Comment: What would be a situation where a successful build wouldn't create the files you need wherever you expect them? Your solution file and your project must be configured for that, possibly including post-build events for copying files outside the VS control to the appropriate place.

Comment: That's excaclty what I want to verify, because a post build step fails only if the last command fails. Because I didn't figure out a simple solution to fail the postbuild step if at least one command fails

Comment: There are also other files which are copied to the output directory by the build script which must be verified too

Answer (score 0):

If the build succeeded, then all the files will be there (assuming configured correctly).  If not configured correctly, then you'd need to specify outside of the specification (i.e. solution/project files) a list of files that you are expecting.

At that point it becomes a case of creating a .txt or .xml file which checks `File.Exists` - very straightforward indeed.  Unless you want to check for more than that?

(I don't do this in my projects - a solution either builds, or doesn't.  Proper QA procedures check the app runs OK, not just looking for files)

Comment: I can think also of testing file versions and / or assembly signing, sure I can roll this on my own but maybe there are already some tools around?